# missing 2 required positional arguments in optimization problem in python

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, scipy-optimize

I'm trying to solve an optimization problem using scipy. There's a huge database that I re-arranged in order to use some of the rows as parameters in the optimization problem. Then I take the sum of each entry and multiply by x variables in order to create constraints that must be greater than "arb" (which is just a new single variable). When I try to solve it I get TypeError: constraint1() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'x' and 'row1'.

```
path = r'mypath/*.csv'

#Extract data
all_rec = iglob(path, recursive=True)
df = (pd.read_csv(f, usecols=[4]) for f in all_rec)
list = pd.concat(df, axis=1, ignore_index=True)

#Extract arrays
t=0
row1 = list.iloc[t+5] - list.iloc[t]
row2 = list.iloc[t+10] - list.iloc[t]
row3 = list.iloc[t+15] - list.iloc[t]
row4 = list.iloc[t+20] - list.iloc[t]

#LP Problem
def objective(arb, sign=-1.0):
    return sign*arb

def constraint1(arb,x,row1):
    for i in range(len(list.columns)):
        sum_cons1 = sum(row1[i]*x[i]) - arb
    return sum_cons1

def constraint2(arb,x,row2):
    for i in range(len(list.columns)):
        sum_cons2 = sum(row2[i]*x[i]) - arb
    return sum_cons2

def constraint3(arb,x,row3):
    for i in range(len(list.columns)):
        sum_cons3 = sum(row3[i]*x[i]) - arb
    return sum_cons3

def constraint4(arb,x,row4):
    for i in range(len(list.columns)):
        sum_cons4 = sum(row4[i]*x[i]) - arb
    return sum_cons4

con1 = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraint1}
con2 = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraint2}
con3 = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraint3}
con4 = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraint4}

cons = ([con1,con2,con3,con4])
solution = minimize(objective,x0=2500.0,method='SLSQP',constraints=cons)
print(solution)
```

Comment: In the objective and constrain functions, `arb` is the optimization variable, which has the initial value of `x0`.  But where is `x` and `row#` supposed to come from?  The globals `row#` won't be passed as arguments.  What is `x`? `minimize` takes an `args` tuple, that can be used to passed extra arguments to these functions.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the constraint function must accept a single argument x and have an output which is the distance from the constraint. For an inequality constraint the minimizer will attempt to keep the returned values in the non-negative range and for an equality it will try to bring it to 0. Your functions however require 3 arguments: x,arb and row.

It seems that you want the `row1,row2,row3` and `row4` to be a global variables, so there's no need for it to be an argument, the minimizer doesn't even know what these variables are. And so does the `arb` argument, did you mean to define it globally?

Comment: No, I meant to define it just within the optimization problem as the objective function, which in this case is just this variable. You are right with the row argument, I don't need it as an argument, but still, x is marked as 'required positional argument'. I'm trying to build within the constraint an array of x number of variables to do the sum-product with the parameters in my database.

Comment: In any case, the minimizers expects a function of a single argument. You can't just expect it to guess what x is or what arb is and pass it to your function. I'm not sure if I understand but perhaps instead of - arb just write - x ?